# Prevent multiple fetches when multiple components use the same React Hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

How can I prevent multiple data fetches when this hook is used in multiple components? It doesn't need to refetch it when the URL stays the same, only when `searchQuery` changes. I also want to be able to call `loadPeople()` with parameters in all components.

What I tried was checking if `people.data` was filled before executing `fetchData()` but that way `loadPeople()` will never work again.

```js
type UseStarWarsProps = {
    people: AsyncData<ApiStarWarsPerson[]>;
    loadPeople: (query?: string) => void;
};

export const useStarWars = (): UseStarWarsProps => {
    const [searchQuery, setSearchQuery] = useState('');
    const people: AsyncData<ApiStarWarsPerson[]> = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.starWars.people);
    const apiProxy: ApiProxyType = ApiProxy();
    let dispatch = useDispatch();

    const fetchData = async () => {
        dispatch(setLoaderStarWarsAction());
        try {
            const data = await apiProxy.getStarWarsPeople(searchQuery);
            dispatch(setStarWarsAction(data.results));
        } catch (e) {
            dispatch(setErrorStarWarsAction(e));
        }
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchData();
    }, [searchQuery]);

    const loadPeople = (query?: string) => {
        setSearchQuery(query || '');
    };

    return { people, loadPeople };
};
```

Comment: You can create in-memory cache for the hook to use. The hook will keep track of whatever requests is currently running along with the searchQuery used as the key. The hook would check if any request with the same searchQuery is currently on progress, if there are, then just wait for it. If there isn't, then start the request. Once the request succeeded, the hook can update the cache with the data.

Comment: This sounds like a very good use case for [redux-saga](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga)